# How to show when Chrome extensions place stylesheets into the document?

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

While using the Dev tools console, I recently logged `document.stylesheets`.  Interestingly, although the page I was working on only had 1 stylesheet there were two stylesheets listed.

Then I realized that my extensions, in this case Adblocker, insert stylesheets to hide or show things.

Is there a way we can either find out where the stylesheets come from (because the `href` tag is not filled out) or make it more obvious that the stylesheets are local?

Comment: count the number loaded on page load, then poll and alert when the number changes

Comment: Some/many/all adblockers insert their stylesheets *before* the page is loaded by utilizing `"run_at": "document_start"`. So they might add the stylesheets even before `<head>` element finished loading, thus counting won't be useful.